# cmake framework target does not copy header or resource?

Tags: macos, frameworks, cmake

I am trying to create an OS X framework using [cmake](https://cmake.org). This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project( Foo)

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)

add_library( Foo SHARED
foo.c
)

set_target_properties( Foo PROPERTIES
FRAMEWORK TRUE
RESOURCE "foo.md"
PUBLIC_HEADER "foo.h"
)
```

When I run `( mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake .. ; make)` a `Foo.framework` is generated, but the header and the resource do not appear in it. What am I missing ? (cmake version 3.7.1)

---

How to reproduce. Save above CMakeLists.txt. Now execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "int version = 1;" > foo.c
touch foo.h
touch foo.md
( mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake .. ; make)
ls -R build/Foo.framework/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `PUBLIC_HEADER` to your `add_library`:

```
project( Foo )

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)

add_library( Foo SHARED
    foo.c
    foo.h
)

set_target_properties( Foo PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    RESOURCE "foo.md"
    PUBLIC_HEADER "foo.h"
)
```

Cmake doesn't know where to copy the header file from unless you add it to the target. Rebuilding will now copy `foo.h` into `Foo.framework/Headers/`. There might be other ways to do this, but this certainly creates the desired result.

Even if you add the headers via the `target_include_directories` function it will not pick up the header file and this makes sense because, CMake doesn't know about any file that wasn't explicitly added to a target.

Comment: Another way is using target_sources() function: `target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${HEADERS})`